# JTable adding new row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with 5 rows at the time of design. Now i have to add more rows as i go dynamically. I am getting array out of bound exception error when i add more rows. How do i solve this issue ?

```
item_list = new javax.swing.JTable();  
item_list.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(  
    new Object [][] {  
        {null, null, null},  
        {null, null, null},  
        {null, null, null},  
        {null, null, null}  
    },  
    new String [] {  
        "No.", "Description", "Cost"  
    }  
) {  
    Class[] types = new Class [] {  
        java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Float.class  
    };

    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {  
        return types [columnIndex];  
    }  
});  
item_list.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(30);  
item_list.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);  
item_list.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(50);  
jScrollPane2.setViewportView(item_list);
```

Comment: What kind of Table model are you using? DefaultTableModel, one of your own making?

Comment: i am usign DefaultTableModel. but i removed a column and changed the width of each columns..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works for me

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Grow extends JFrame {

    private static final Object[][] rowData = {{"Hello", "World"}};
    private static final Object[] columnNames = {"A", "B"};

    private JTable table;
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    public Grow() {
         Container c = getContentPane();
         c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

         model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
         table = new JTable();
         table.setModel(model);
         c.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
         JButton add = new JButton("Add");
         c.add(add, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                 model.addRow(rowData[0]);
             }
         });
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         pack(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Grow g = new Grow();
        g.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        g.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Deepak, we are not here to spoon feed you code. You where asked to post a SSCCE and you didn't. You have been asked to read the API and it also appear you haven't since your code does not use the addRow(...) method. You've been given some working code to look at, so take a look at it and ask specific questions if you don't understand it. Compare the working code with your code to see what is different.

Comment: My code is just initializing the table and i didnt add any rows to it. I just placed values on the already created model. When i used getModel() i am not gettign crazy string which i cant understand. I used getmodel and then using the returned model object i tried to use addRow() but i am not getting addRow() method in it.. now help me...

Comment: @Deepak, We can't help you. The code you posted doesn't even compile. Again I will repeat myself. YOu've been given working code that shows you how to use the addRow(...) method. Compare the working code with your code to see what is different.

Comment: btw, you should never use DefaultTableModel, it is an abomination http://jroller.com/dbrosius/entry/defaulttablemodel_just_say_no

Answer (score 4):

I assume You have a table with six column.
Follow this code ,it will append a new row to already existing table

```
DefaultTableModel defaultModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        Vector newRow = new Vector();
        newRow.add("Total Amount Spend");
        newRow.add(TotalAmt);
        newRow.add(Apaid);
        newRow.add(Bpaid);
        newRow.add(Cpaid);
        newRow.add(Dpaid);
        defaultModel.addRow(newRow);
```

Where JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);

Answer (score 3):

The DefaultTableModel has an addRow(...) method that you should be using.

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Read the API, that is where you will find the methods available for any class.