# JTable Refresh using TableModel

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I have been trying to refresh my Jtable but I think I'm somehow getting confused with the tableModel and Table Model listener concepts.

So I construct a table by passing a datastructure in the TableModel class

```
public class TasksTableModel extends AbstractTableModel  {
    int[] collect;    
    String[]   columnNames;    
    Object[][] data;    

    public TasksTableModel(int[] collect) {
        this.collect=collect;
        columnNames=new String[]{"Job","Task"}; 
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
           data[i][0]=collect[0];
           data[i][1]=collect[1];
        }
    }
 }    

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }
}
```

My table is created in another class like this 
 `TasksTableModel model = new TasksTableModel(tc);
        tcTable = new JTable(model);`

So there is an update to my collect[] object after which i need to refresh the table.So far,I have been setting the table to a new TaskTableModel to refresh where I lose any sorting on existing table.How should I go about doing so. Please provide a sample code for my better understanding.

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/); here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100822/jtable-adding-new-row/5101107#5101107).

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the `TasksTableModel` to separate setting the model from the constructor, for example:

```
public TasksTableModel(int[] collect) {
    columnNames=new String[]{"Job","Task"};
    setModel(collect);
}

public void setModel(int[] collect) {
    this.collect=collect;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        data[i][0]=collect[0];
        data[i][1]=collect[1];
    }
}
```

Then when you want to update the `collect[]` object, do:

```
model.setModel(collect);
model.fireTableDataChanged();
```

Comment: noooo ... don't fire any events on behalf of the model, that's the inherent responsibility of the model _itself_ (that is do so at the end of the setModel(...) )